# CSS triangle border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a tag shape with CSS. With following code, I can display the tag correctly with the arrow on the left side, How can I move the arrow to the right side of the div instead of the left?

HTML:

```
<div class="tags">
    <a href="#">tag</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tags a{
    float:left;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;     
    margin-left:20px;
    padding:0 10px 0 12px;
    background:#0089e0;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
} 

.tags a:before{
    content:"";
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-12px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent #0089e0 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px 12px 12px 0;      
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/TXLBT/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just by changing a few CSS styles:

```
.tags a:after{
    content:"";
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-12px; //Change here
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #0089e0; //Change here
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px 0 12px 12px; //Change here
}
```

It's rather self-explanitory: It is now positioned from the right and right and left border attributes get swapped. (Except of course for `border-style`)

FYI: Floating an element will have no effect on it if it is positioned absolutely.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXLBT/2/)

Answer (score 2):

[Forked your code here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/pYy6L/).

Essentially, you need to changes instances of `left` for `right` (whether it's `::before` or `::after`, and the `float` direction, are immaterial, since the pseudo-element is absolutely positioned). When doing this, bear in mind that `border-color` and `border-style` actually reference top, right, bottom and left, in that order.

So the properties you are changing are:

```
left:-12px;
border-color:transparent #0089e0 transparent transparent;
border-width:12px 12px 12px 0;
```

to

```
right:-12px;
border-color:transparent transparent transparent #0089e0;
border-width:12px 0 12px 12px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Position the :before to the right and set the border to be transparent at all sides except the left instead of the right.