# draw a triangle in css which have only borders

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a triangle in css which contain only borders. no background colors.

```
.arrow {
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
border-top: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid #000;
height: 0;
width: 0px;
}
```

The above code gives me a triangle with #000 as background colors. i just want the triangle borders.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231184/create-a-triangle-with-css

Comment: Can you set the background color to transparent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS triangle border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110137/css-triangle-border)

Comment: setting it to transparent will make the triangle invisible

Comment: The code you're using now [creates a triangle just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/k3x9w/)...

Answer (score 1):

```
.arrow:after {
 content: '\25c1';
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: will this have support across all browser?

Comment: It's not going to work on lynx or anything, but generated content works great on most browsers - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent